# Python requires libmysqlclient.22.dylib but libmysqlclient.23.dylib exist

Tags: python, mysql

I bumped into this error.
when running django script using mysql

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/whitebear/.local/share/virtualenvs/cinnamon-admin-mg9y4sUV/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.22.dylib
```

There is no `/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.22.dylib`, but

there is /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.23.dylib instead.

> mysql --version
> mysql  Ver 8.3.0 for macos14.2 on arm64 (Homebrew)

> python --version
> Python 3.9.18

So I guess I should update `python` to another version, or downgrade `mysql`

Am I correct?

If so which version should I update to?

Comment: To be honest when this has happened to me, I just make a symbolic link of the library that is installed, naming the link whatever the dependent software wants. Almost every time, the library versions at least are compatible with respect to entry points, so it works well enough for a development environment. I wouldn't do this for a production environment though.

Comment: Another solution is to get the source for the dependent project and build it yourself. Or else file an issue with that project and let them know that they need to bump their versions and release a new package. But if you need it right away, build it yourself from source.

Comment: Thank you very much @Bill Karwin. I tried the first suggestion, make symbolic link named `libmysqlclient.23.dylib`  to `libmysqlclient.22.dylib`, however python crashes with sigmentation fault

Comment: OK, remove that symbolic link, obviously this is a case where the versions of the client are not compatible. :-)

Comment: THank you @Bill Karwin, I updated the python 3.9 to 3.12 and it fixed.